# Unity Particles Arent Deleting But Emitting After Finishing

Tags: unity-game-engine

so I been searching for hours on how to fix this problem but I couldn't find a solution so I wanted to ask here I have a walking particle [VIDEO](https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/565431507) < ***as you can see in the video AFTER I walk 3 to 2 secs later the particles will

heres my code on my update I made it so it should check if we are moving to the right with the joystick then show it and if we are moving to the left with the joystick then it should show it as well but for some reason after that 2 to 3 secs the emittating wiill start[[image]]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgkfg.png)
[image]

```
   void Update()
    {

        if (joystick.Horizontal >= .2f)
        {

            hays.SetActive(true);
            Instantiate(hays, particleposition.transform.position, hays.transform.rotation);




        }



        if (joystick.Horizontal <= -.2f)
        {
            hays.SetActive(true);

            Instantiate(hays, particleposition.transform.position, hays.transform.rotation);



        }
```

what I tried
I tried checking if its not doing the above code then it should just delete but it doesnt work at all it will still imitate  I also tried checking the animation state but it still the same thing it wont stop imitating

```
        if (joystick.Horizontal !>= .2f)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
        }

        if (joystick.Horizontal !<= -.2f)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
        }
```

my full code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class partscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Joystick joystick;
    public GameObject hays;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    float horizontalMove = 0f;
    public bool show = true;
    public Animator animator2;
    public Transform player;
    public Transform  particleposition; 
    


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = particleposition.position;
    animator2 = GetComponent<Animator>();
        //Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
    }
    //destroy(hays);
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (joystick.Horizontal >= .2f)
        {

            hays.SetActive(true);
            Instantiate(hays, particleposition.transform.position, hays.transform.rotation);




        }



        if (joystick.Horizontal <= -.2f)
        {
            hays.SetActive(true);

            Instantiate(hays, particleposition.transform.position, hays.transform.rotation);



        }


        if (joystick.Horizontal !>= .2f)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
        }

        if (joystick.Horizontal !<= -.2f)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
        }










    }
}
```

Comment: Your use of the `!` symbol in `(joystick.Horizontal !>= .2f)` isn't doing what you think it's doing.  There are a couple of meanings for the `!` symbol in C# 8.0.  It can be used to negate a boolean expression i.e `!(1 > 0)` would equal `false` because `1 > 0` is `true` and the `!` negates it.  The way you use it in your expression though is as a null forgiving operator - all it is doing in your expression is telling the compiler that `joystick.Horizontal` is not `null`.  Change the expression to`if (!(joystick.Horizontal >= .2f))` to negate the boolean expression.

Comment: Could you show us the configuration of your particle system .. sounds like you have configured a time based emitter in the emission module

Comment: Okay give me a sec

Comment: ok I added the images refresh to see them

Comment: HumanWrites I did what you said but my particles woudlnt sstop destroying after I start moving I will get an error "The object of type GameObject has been destroyed but you are still trying to acess it" it's suppose to be destroying only if I'm not moving but it will keep destroying even though I'm moving

Answer (score 0):

removed loop and changed the duration to 1 and it started to work